# Would a ton of bricks be the same amount of bricks today as it was 1000 years ago?

Tags: gravity, weight

As the earth wanders through space it collects mass constantly. This is observable as meteorites and craters etc. As mass increases so does the gravitational field of the planet. So wouldnt a ton of bricks today contain less bricks than a ton of bricks contained 1000 years ago here on earth?

Comment: While Earth accumulates about forty tons of solid material every day, the Earth also loses about one hundred tons of atmosphere to space in the same period ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/10/science/earth-size-mass.html)). Note that this is a part-per-$10^{18}$ correction to the Earth's mass, while "a ton of bricks" is not generally weighed so precisely. Note also that we distinguish between weight, which depends on the local gravitational field, versus mass, which is an intrinsic property of matter.

Comment: A ton of bricks contains fewer bricks at the equator than at the poles. This effect is far greater than any effect due to relatively minute changes in the Earth's mass.